# hyperleder-composer query language CONTAINS operator with Boolean Expression

Tags: hyperledger-composer, named-query

In my hyperledger composer app I want to write a named query that returns all persons with two specified hobbies.

The model for "Person" is the following:

```
participant Person identified by id {
  o String id
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
  o String email
  --> Hobby[] hobbies optional
}
```

The model for "Hobby" is the following:

```
asset Hobby identified by id {
  o String id
  o String name
}
```

The named query has the following structure:

```
query selectPersonsByHobbies {
  description: "Select all persons with the two specified hobbies."
  statement:
      SELECT org.comp.myapp.Person
          WHERE //not sure what to put here//
}
```

I'm not sure what to put after the "WHERE" operator in order to achieve what I want.

Is this correct?:

```
query selectPersonsByHobbies {
      description: "Select all persons with the two specified hobbies."
      statement:
          SELECT org.comp.myapp.Person
              WHERE (hobbies CONTAINS ((name == _$hobby1) AND (name == _$hobby2)))
}
```

Or is the following correct?:

```
query selectPersonsByHobbies {
      description: "Select all persons with the two specified hobbies."
      statement:
          SELECT org.comp.myapp.Person
              WHERE (hobbies CONTAINS (name == _$hobby1) AND CONTAINS (name == _$hobby2))
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Following the answer suggested by Paul O'Mahony, here is how I understand the situation:

Given the following model for "Person":

```
participant Person identified by id {
  o String id
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
  o String email
  o Hobby[] hobbies optional
}
```

and the following model for Hobby:

```
asset Hobby identified by id {
  o String id
  o String name
}
```

the following query would succeed in returning all persons with the two specified hobbies:

```
query selectPersonsByHobbies {
  description: "Select all persons with the two specified hobbies."
  statement:
      SELECT org.comp.myapp.Person 
  WHERE ( hobbies CONTAINS [ _$hobby1,  _$hobby2] )
}
```

.... the parameter values sent with the query (and to be inserted for _$hobby1 and _$hobby2, respectively) would have be the Ids of the respective hobbies, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can't presently, in the Composer Query language,  use an aggregate 'AND' in Concepts for CONTAINS currently in the fashion you suggest (OR is fine, but AND you can't) - the name field is compared for each class entry (and it can't be both at the same time with AND). In 0.19.12 onwards of Composer - you could use a `getnativeAPI()` from a readonly Trxn Processor function to make the equivalent CONTAINS call natively to CouchDB query language.

The AND (as requested above) would work if the field was a String array eg `String[] hobbies` eg.

```
query selectPersonsByHobbies {
  description: "Select all persons with the two specified hobbies."
  statement:
      SELECT org.comp.myapp.Person 
  WHERE ( hobbies CONTAINS [ _$hobby1,  _$hobby2] )
}
```

but your field on `Person` would have to be `Hobby[] hobbies optional` (ie not an array of relationships ie relationship IDs as it is presently - ).

Comment: thank you for your answer ... I summarised my understanding of your answer in the "UPDATE" section of my post ... Is my understanding correct?

Comment: correct, that's how that particular query (find Person with hobby1 and hobby2 passed as parms)  is supposed to work.